# Change repository permission in TFS/VSTS/Azure DevOps with command line

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I'm trying to change the permission of about 250 folders in Azure DevOps (VSTS), the source control is TFVC, and it is quite slow to change just 10 of them using the web interface.

Is there a command line tool that I can set the permission to a directory? For example, adding the **A Contributors** group to the directory **/Release/v1/ProjectA** and **B Contributors** group to the directory **/Release/v1/ProjectB**. I'm hoping this way I can just iterate through all the releases.

I was looking at **TFSecurity.exe** but it doesn't seem to be able to change the permission of individual folders. Or perhaps I missed something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out **TF.exe** is the answer. For some reason I overlooked the **Permission** command.

The following enables inheritance for **/Release/v1/ProjectA** and adds a set of permission to the security group **Contributors A**:

```
.\TF.exe vc permission /inherit:yes "/Release/v1/ProjectA"
.\TF.exe vc permission /allow:"Read, PendChange, Checkin, Label, Lock, Merge" /group:"[Project]/Contributors A" "/Release/v1/ProjectA"
```

Answer (score 1):

So, there's a [Microsoft VSTS CLI](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vsts.cli) in the marketplace and it has most of the basic commands you'd need. Unfortunately, when looking for permissions and repo security configuration commands, there are currently none.

Taking a look at their [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-cli), they do have an [open issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-cli/issues/165) for this exact command which would be a new feature.

Sorry!

Comment: Thanks for the link to the open issue. Our repo is using TFVC, if that matters.